Inertia field example of $ \mathbb{Q}_5(\sqrt[4]{50})$
Let $L = \mathbb{Q}_5(\sqrt[4]{50})$ and denote by $E$ the inertia field of the extension $L / \mathbb{Q}_5$. Write down a prime element $\pi_E $ of $ \mathcal{O}_E $ with $L = E(\sqrt{\pi_E})$. Can one choose $\pi_E$ in $\mathbb{Q}_5$?
I’m studying this problem. And I have a hard time writing out everything, especially the look of E (inertia field).
I know that the inertia field is of form
$E =\mathbb{Q}_5(\omega)$ where $\omega$ denotes the
$ (|\kappa_L| - 1) - st$ root of unity.
Further I know that $E/ \mathbb{Q}_5$ is unramified, thus every prime element of $\mathbb{Q}_5$ is also a prime element of $E$ making $5$ an prime element also for $E$.
From an exercise I know that the minimal polynomial a prime element of $L = \mathbb{Q}_5(\sqrt[4]{50})$ namely $\pi_{L}$ is Eisenstein and also that also that $ E[\pi_L] = L $. Further we have the equivalence that $ L/E $ totally ramified iff there is an Eisenstein polynomial $ f(x) $ in $ E[X] $  and some $ \alpha $ in $ L $ with $ f(\alpha) = 0 $ and $ L = E[\alpha] $.
The minimal polynomial is $ x^4 - 50 $ with the roots $ \sqrt[4]{50}, -\sqrt[4]{50}, \sqrt[4]{50}i, \sqrt[4]{50}(-i) $. So the degree and hence ramification index $ e = 4 $.
Can someone help me out to explicitly write out the inertia field? I am trying to understand the concept of unramified and totally ramified field extensions better with the idea of the inertia field. And this exercise was given to us.
Sincerely Chris

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

On this site, LaTeX is surrounded by simple dollarsigns ($E$) instead of backslashed ones (\$ E \$). Can you also complete your question?

Thank you I fixed it

maybe $E=\mathbb{Q}_5(\sqrt2)$ and $\pi_E=5\sqrt2$?

Have you gotten through to full understanding yet? The comment of @user8268 gives the answer, but without explanation. Here’s how I look at things.
Your extension is quartic, so you might as well think of it as a tower of two quadratic extensions, $\Bbb Q_5\subset\Bbb Q_5(50^{1/2})\subset\Bbb Q_5(50^{1/4})$.
The first extension is achieved by adjoining $\sqrt2$ to $\Bbb Q_5$, and this is unramified, since $2$ has no square root in the residue field $\Bbb F_5=\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$.The characteristic-five extension $\Bbb F_5\subset\Bbb F_5(\sqrt2)$ gives you a (the) field with $25$ elements, and the corresponding extension upstairs in characteristic zero is your unramified extension $\Bbb Q_5(\sqrt2)=\Bbb Q_5(50^{1/2})$. Therefore the residue-field extension degree, $f$, is equal to two, and there’s your inertia field $E=\Bbb Q_5(\sqrt2)$.
For the upper extension, you may treat the minimal polynomial of the generator $50^{1/4}$ as $X^2-50^{1/2}=X^2-5\sqrt2\in E[X]$. Look at it and you see that it’s an Eisenstein polynomial since $\sqrt2$ is a unit, $5$-adically. There’s your evaluation of the ramification index, $e=2$, and your $\pi_E$ is $5\sqrt2$.
Perhaps the most interesting question is whether the top field can be expressed as $E(\sqrt{5u})$ for $u$ a unit in $\Bbb Z_5$. I’m afraid I don’tknow a slick argument for why this is not possible without appealing to something perhaps more advanced than where you are. Let me sneak in an argument from Kummer Theory, though. I hope you know that in characteristic zero, two quadratic extensions of the same field $k$ are equal, $k(\sqrt a)=k(\sqrt b)$, if and only if $a/b$ is a square in $k$.
Thus my task is to show that $5\sqrt2/5u$ can not be a square in $E=\Bbb Q_5(\sqrt2)$, for $u$ a unit of $\Bbb Z_5$. Perhaps clearest to argue down in characteristic five, where everything is happening in $\Bbb F_{25}$, the quadratic extension of the  prime field, and where the multiplicative group is of order $24$, and cyclic. In this group, $\sqrt2$ is a primitive eighth root of unity, and so not a square, whereas any unit from $\Bbb Z_5$, and thus nonzero in $\Bbb F_5$, is a square. Their quotient is, as a result, not a square, so that $5\sqrt2/5u$ is not a square in $E$.
